# Is it against the convention to use a number at the start of a boolean variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, boolean

Is it against the convention of Objective C 2.0 to declare a boolean value starting with a number ex. 123bool?

Comment: what do you mean by a lot of booleans?  Unless this is a quantum system a boolean is either True or False

Comment: You mean you're declaring them like `BOOL myBool23;`?

Comment: sounds like some kind of dictionary would be more effective instead of having lots of variables.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are not using one or more arrays for all these booleans ?

Comment: Is your question is if it's bad to use digits in the name of a variable? It's fine to use them like you did in your example. Although, if it's all FOO1, FOO2, ... FOO346, you might be better off using an array of size 346 (at least you won't have to declare such a massive number). Although, it'd definitely be better to give them descriptive names.

Comment: maybe you should look for c-style arrays you just need bools and no objects ... much better performance then (ns)dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use array? `BOOL foos[400];` I think it is very bad to declare so many BOOL variables and the name is almost the same. BTW, don't uppercase the first letter of your variable, it's a bad coding style.

Comment: Actually, this will not, you can access it like foo[0], foo[1] and so on.

Comment: Yes, and most of the time you should try this before you ask. I'm not looking down on you but these question is quite fundamentel. Just write some code and run it! It will be exciting! Good luck to you.

Comment: Don't feel sorry for this, because everyone begins from zero. You are welcome to ask questions that you can't handle. Enthusiastic guys are here to answer it for you!